# Quickest way to give file name the current date on Linux

Tags: linux, thunar

There are a lot of occurrences in which I want to name a file or directory something with the current date in it. Mostly it's temporary backups that I take every once in a while, just in case I mess up something later.

And since an exported file, for example a database, will always have the same name, being that I don't want to overwrite an older temp backup, the best solution is to give it a date. And I am very tired of typing in the current date, as well as the underscores, but I am even more tired of hovering over my clock to check what the date is.

So I am wondering if there is any shortcut to paste the current date built in? If not, can I create one? What is the quickest way to make it easier to name a file/folder the current date?

Answer (score 7):

In a shell, use command substitution:

```
touch "$(date)"
```

or, with format

```
touch "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S)"
```

You can keep the longer command in an alias or function

```
alias ts='date +%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S'
touch "$(ts)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Following choroba's advice, you could define a [custom action](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions) on Thunar's context menu

Answer (score 1):

There were multiple ways to append the file :

From [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795678/append-date-to-filename-in-linux) :

1. Get the date as a string

This is pretty easy. Just use the date command with the + option. We can use backticks to capture the value in a variable.

```
$ DATE=`date +%d-%m-%y`
```

You can change the date format by using different % options as detailed on the date [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date).

2. Split a file into name and extension.

This is a bit trickier. If we think they'll be only one . in the filename we can use cut with . as the delimiter.

```
$ NAME=`echo $FILE | cut -d. -f1
$ EXT=`echo $FILE | cut -d. -f2`
```

However, this won't work with multiple . in the file name. If we're using bash - which you probably are - we can use some bash magic that allows us to match patterns when we do variable expansion:

```
$ NAME=${FILE%.*}
$ EXT=${FILE#*.}
```

Putting them together we get:

```
$ FILE=somefile.txt             
$ NAME=${FILE%.*}
$ EXT=${FILE#*.} 
$ DATE=`date +%d-%m-%y`         
$ NEWFILE=${NAME}_${DATE}.${EXT}
$ echo $NEWFILE                 
somefile_05-10-15.txt
```

And if we're less worried about readability we do all the work on one line (with a different date format):

```
$ FILE=somefile.txt  
$ FILE=${FILE%.*}_`date +%d%b%y`.${FILE#*.}
$ echo $FILE                                 
somefile_05oct15.txt
```

Other ways would be :

$ date
Wed Oct 16 19:20:51 EDT 2013

If you truly want filenames like that you'll need to wrap that string in quotes.

$ touch "foo.backup.$(date)"

$ ll foo*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Oct 16 19:22 foo.backup.Wed Oct 16 19:22:29 EDT 2013

You're probably thinking of a different string to be appended would be my guess though. I usually use something like this:

```
$ touch "foo.backup.$(date +%F_%R)"
$ ll foo*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 saml saml 0 Oct 16 19:25 foo.backup.2013-10-16_19:25
```

See the man page for date for more formatting codes around the output for the date & time.
Additional formats

If you want to take full control if you consult the man page you can do things like this:

```
$ date +"%Y%m%d"
20131016

$ date +"%Y-%m-%d"
2013-10-16

$ date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
20131016_193655
```